# Restore GitLab 6.9.1 backup to new GitLab 7.14 instance

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gitlab, restore, gitlab-7, gitlab-omnibus

I'm in the process of building a new server to upgrade from GitLab 6.9.1 to the latest version of `GitLab` (7.14.1) on `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.

I've created a backup of the `GitLab` instance using the following command:

`sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create`

I've copied the backup to the new server and placed it `/var/opt/gitlab/backups/`.

When I run the command to restore the backup on the new server with the new GitLab instance

`sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1442406091`

I get the following error:

```
Unpacking backup ... done
GitLab version mismatch:
  Your current GitLab version (7.14.3) differs from the GitLab version in the backup!
  Please switch to the following version and try again:
  version: 6.9.1

Hint: git checkout v6.9.1
```

I've read in the GitLab documentation that a restore is only possible from the same version of GitLab but is there a way to restore the backup from 6.9.1 to a new fresh instance of 7.14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just done something very similar, the only way I found that worked is to just install the same version as your old install (6.9.1) as a deb from https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/archives/, restore from your backup in to it, then upgrade gitlab-ce using `apt-get upgrade gitlab-ce`.  Hope that helps.